# on Emacs for OSX, how to keep kill ring and clipboard separate?

Tags: emacs, clipboard, aquamacs, kill-ring

In GNU Emacs for OSX, how can I keep the kill ring and OSX clipboard separate? (Such that I essentially have two separate kill rings.)

With desired behavior, this would work:
1. <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> to copy text from the web to OSX clipboard.
2. <kbd>control</kbd><kbd>k</kbd> to kill a line in Emacs.
3. <kbd>control</kbd><kbd>y</kbd> to yank killed text from Emacs kill ring to current Emacs buffer.
4. <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>v</kbd> to paste original web text from OSX clipboard to current Emacs buffer.

This works out of the box in Aquamacs. How to make work in GNU Emacs?

This question was discussed as it pertains to Windows here:
[Emacs: How to separate the kill ring from the system clipboard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6870979/emacs-how-to-separate-the-kill-ring-from-the-system-clipboard/22849033#22849033)

and here:
http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/help-emacs-windows/2010-02/msg00001.HTML

...but this solution does not work in OSX. I would like a solution for Mac OSX.

Comment: Related option which doesn't answer your question, but solved the problem in a way I didn't even expect was possible: [`save-interprogram-paste-before-kill`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Clipboard.html). It keeps the sync between clipboard and kill ring, but saves your OS clipboard on the kill ring before clobbering it. Still accessible, and fully integrated. E.g. your example would only change on step 4: `C-y M-y` instead of `⌘-v`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The solution in [Emacs: How to separate the kill ring from the system clipboard?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6870979) does work, though not complete. You may call `pbcopy` yourself to get clipboard pasting right. For instance, try the following in your `.emacs`. Note that `s-v` is for `Cmd+V` in an OS X window system. Same goes for `s-c`.

```lisp
;;; Tested on:
;;; 1.  GNU Emacs 24.3.1 (x86_64-apple-darwin13.0.0)
;;;     of 2013-12-22 on tennine-slave.macports.org
;;;     (MacPorts emacs@24.3_1)
;;;
;;; 2.  GNU Emacs 24.3.1 (x86_64-apple-darwin, NS apple-appkit-1038.36)
;;;     of 2013-03-12 on bob.porkrind.org
;;;     (Emacs For Mac OS X)

(defun isolate-kill-ring()
  "Isolate Emacs kill ring from OS X system pasteboard.
This function is only necessary in window system."
  (interactive)
  (setq interprogram-cut-function nil)
  (setq interprogram-paste-function nil))

(defun pasteboard-copy()
  "Copy region to OS X system pasteboard."
  (interactive)
  (shell-command-on-region
   (region-beginning) (region-end) "pbcopy"))

(defun pasteboard-paste()
  "Paste from OS X system pasteboard via `pbpaste' to point."
  (interactive)
  (shell-command-on-region
   (point) (if mark-active (mark) (point)) "pbpaste" nil t))

(defun pasteboard-cut()
  "Cut region and put on OS X system pasteboard."
  (interactive)
  (pasteboard-copy)
  (delete-region (region-beginning) (region-end)))

(if window-system
    (progn
      (isolate-kill-ring)
      ;; bind CMD+C to pasteboard-copy
      (global-set-key (kbd "s-c") 'pasteboard-copy)
      ;; bind CMD+V to pasteboard-paste
      (global-set-key (kbd "s-v") 'pasteboard-paste)
      ;; bind CMD+X to pasteboard-cut
      (global-set-key (kbd "s-x") 'pasteboard-cut))

  ;; you might also want to assign some keybindings for non-window
  ;; system usage (i.e., in your text terminal, where the
  ;; command->super does not work)
  )
```

If you ever run into problems with UTF-8, consider the following possible solution:

```lisp
;; handle emacs utf-8 input
(set-terminal-coding-system 'utf-8)
(set-keyboard-coding-system 'utf-8)
(prefer-coding-system 'utf-8)
(setenv "LANG" "en_US.UTF-8")
```

Comment: Well you asked "Well so what's the code to set interprogram-cut-function to nil?" in that question. Of course you put the above code in your `.emacs`, or `M-x`/`M-:` on the go.

Comment: This doesn't work. It fails to paste text from the OSX clipboard.

Comment: I've updated my answer to solve the OS X clipboard pasting problem. Hope it helps. (And hope someone could clear that downvote. The previous solution didn't really deserve a downvote — this is not meta, AFAIK people only down vote totally irrelevant answers, not partial solutions.)

Comment: Also added pbcopy keybinding.

Comment: That works! There is still one problem: after `s-v` to `paste clipboard`, the point is still before the inserted text. The point should be after the inserted/pasted text. Thanks.

Comment: @PeterSalazar Sorry I overlooked this. Now fixed.

Comment: Excellent! That works now. One last thing: we need to create a function for `s-x`, i.e. `pbcut`, which I guess just means pbcopy plus delete region? Maybe after that you could publish this as a package!

Comment: @PeterSalazar Good point (though I doubt if I'll ever need that). Updated. Also factored out the functions so that you can also call them from tty (or set keybindings for tty). A package is clearly an overkill for something as simple as this. I'll release a gist then.

Comment: There seems to be a problem with the way it pastes whitespace. I just tried to copy and paste five spaces, but it only pasted a single space. It seems to be a problem with the pasting, not the copying.

Comment: @PeterSalazar Could you please give me a minimal working example?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55873/discussion-between-kevinsayhi-and-peter-salazar).

Comment: I see the problem. It was that the `s-v` key binding was not active in the mini buffer. Adding this seems to resolve the issue: `(define-key minibuffer-local-map (kbd "s-v") 'pasteboard-paste)`

Comment: @PeterSalazar Yeah, minibuffer has its own set of local maps.

Comment: I've run into a problem with pasteboard-paste: UTF characters such as `“ ” ' ' – —` get pasted as garbage characters. Is there a way to run the clipboard contents through some kind of UTF filter before pasting?

Comment: @PeterSalazar I just tried pasting `“ ”`, and didn't notice any problem. Maybe there's something wrong with the coding of your buffer?

Comment: Try `C-h v buffer-file-coding-system`. Mine is always `utf-8-unix`.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Are you able to Copy to Clipboard from Chrome and then pasteboard-paste UTF characters, like, say, the first line of this? http://www.csbruce.com/software/utf-8.html

Comment: @PeterSalazar Yup, no problem at all. Tested both in window system and tty. See screenshots: http://i.imgur.com/GsydVgs.png
http://i.imgur.com/oXcxgO9.png

Comment: @PeterSalazar Could you please inspect the value of the variable `buffer-file-coding-system` (as I said above)?

Comment: `Its value is utf-8-unix
Local in buffer 'today.org'; global value is nil`

Comment: more details here http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55873/discussion-between-kevinsayhi-and-peter-salazar

Comment: @PeterSalazar I tried to answer your question in chatroom.

Comment: I found the solution: `(setenv "LANG" "en_US.UTF-8")`. 

Source: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24620039/how-to-pbpaste-utf-8-characters-in-gnu-emacs-for-osx/24639415?iemail=1&noredirect=1#24639415

Comment: @PeterSalazar Okay, so your locale isn't `en_US.UTF-8`. That's the difference between our setups. However, I'd rather be conservative about messing with the locale, so I've separated your workaround from the original code.

Comment: Your solution has been working flawlessly for months. One question: I'm still getting `^M` characters when I copy content from certain apps and use `pasteboard-paste` to paste into Emacs. I can fix this by doing a `replace string` and replacing `^M` with <kbd>C-q C-j</kbd>. However, is there a way to catch this within `pasteboard-paste`?

Comment: @PeterSalazar Glad it helped. Regarding `^M`, most certainly there's a very simple solution. `^M` is CR (carriage return, ASCII `\x0d`). While Unix-like systems (including OS X) uses LF (linefeed) as newline, MS DOS and Windows uses CR+LF, and classic Mac OS uses CR alone. Those are the sources of `^M` you see (for instance, many web page source code uses `CR+LF` as newline — in fact, even some server response headers; and Apple's own script editor uses CR).

Comment: @PeterSalazar If you're sure you never want to see `^M` (I don't), just replace the `"pbpaste"` in the original code with `"pbpaste | perl -p -e 's/\r$//' | tr '\r' '\n'"`. Should take care of both CRLF and CR alone. I'm using perl here because the BSD sed shipped with OS X is so limited that it doesn't even seem to recognize `\r` escape. (Maybe I'm just not good enough with BSD sed; anyway, I don't have the incentive to be good at this crap when GNU sed is much better.) Please inform me of whether this works.

Comment: Any idea how to copy text from the Emacs kill-ring to the OSX pasteboard? Because some functions (e.g. gist-buffer) push output into the kill ring and I'd like to be able to access it from other OSX apps. Thanks!

Comment: @incandescentman You might need to create a temporary buffer with kill ring content and then `shell-command-on-region`.

Comment: @incandescentman Something that might help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15694531/1944784

Answer (score 1):

After much fiddling around, I'm pretty sure that the only way to make this work is to override the `x-select-text` method. Check out my answer here for all the details: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23254771/71522

Comment: It still fails my main test: `org-kill-line` followed by `clipboard-yank` should be independent of each other.

Comment: I (1) evaluated this code: `(defun x-select-text (text))
(setq x-select-enable-clipboard nil)
(setq x-select-enable-primary nil)
(setq mouse-drag-copy-region nil)
(setq interprogram-cut-function 'ns-set-pasteboard)
(setq interprogram-paste-function 'ns-get-pasteboard)`; (2) did `org-kill-line` (3) did `clipboard-yank`. Clipboard yank still inserts the killed text rather than the contents of OSX clipboard... either that or the killed line is going into the OSX clipboard.

Comment: Hrm, annoying. Is the line put on the OS X clipboard? Otherwise, maybe check `org-kill-line` to see what it's doing? (`M-x find-function org-kill-line`)

Comment: I tried it with `M-x kill-line`. The killed text still goes straight into the OSX clipboard.

Answer (score 1):

**NOTE**:  This draft solution is *not* meant to be an Emacs system-wide modification separating the clipboards -- *instead*, this is a custom solution designed to keep the clipboards separated on an `interactive` basis *only* when specifically using these custom functions.  Other functions within 
Emacs that use the `kill-ring` can be modified using a similar method -- the variables `interprogram-cut-function` and `interprogram-paste-function` can be made `let-bound` to a `nil` value for the duration of the specific functions (either through `advice`, or modification of the source itself, or creating new functions and/or using a `defalias`).  However, the latter is beyond the scope of this limited example.

---

HISTORY

**First Draft** (December 23, 2014):  This is a first draft, which is based on the idea that the OSX clipboard may be accessed only when using `C-u` before calling either the copy or paste functions.  If `C-u` is called first, then the OSX clipboard is utilized.  As I use the functions more on a daily basis, I may have additional revisions to this code and I will update same from time to time:

**EDIT** (December 24, 2014):  Removed `*` from the interactive command statement as to `lawlist-copy-selected-region` -- that was a `read-only` check needed for pasting, but not copying.  Added a statement regarding the general nature of this example.

**EDIT** (December 28, 2014):  Revised code to better handle when the user forgot to select a region before calling `lawlist-copy-selected-region`.  Small revisions to make the code more concise.

---

```lisp
(defun lawlist-copy-selected-region (&optional arg)
(interactive "P")
  (let* (
      (interprogram-cut-function
        (when (equal arg '(4)) interprogram-cut-function))
      (interprogram-paste-function
        (when (equal arg '(4)) interprogram-paste-function))
      (region-active-p (region-active-p))
      (beg (when region-active-p (region-beginning)))
      (end (when region-active-p (region-end)))
      (copied-string
        (when region-active-p (buffer-substring-no-properties beg end))) )
    (unless region-active-p
      (let ((debug-on-quit nil))
        (signal 'quit `("No region has been selected!"))))
    (copy-region-as-kill beg end)
    (when (not (active-minibuffer-window))
      (message "%s"
        (concat
          (if (and interprogram-cut-function interprogram-paste-function)
            "OSX+Emacs:  "
            "Emacs:  ")
          (truncate-string-to-width copied-string 40)
          (when (> (length copied-string) 40)
            " . . .")))) ))

(defun lawlist-yank (&optional arg)
  (interactive "*P")
  (unless arg (setq arg 1))
  (setq yank-window-start (window-start))
  (setq this-command t)
  (push-mark (point))
  (insert-for-yank
    (lawlist-current-kill
      (cond
        ((listp arg)
          arg)
        ((eq arg '-)
          -2)
        (t
          (1- arg) ))))
  (if (consp arg)
      (goto-char (prog1 (mark t)
       (set-marker (mark-marker) (point) (current-buffer)))))
  (if (eq this-command t)
      (setq this-command 'yank))
  (when (region-active-p)
    (setq mark-active nil))
  nil)

(defun lawlist-current-kill (n &optional do-not-move)
  (let ((interprogram-paste
          (and
            (equal n '(4))
            interprogram-paste-function
            (funcall interprogram-paste-function))))
    (cond
      (interprogram-paste
        (let ((interprogram-cut-function nil))
          (if (listp interprogram-paste)
            (mapc 'kill-new (nreverse interprogram-paste))
            (kill-new interprogram-paste)))
        (car kill-ring))
      ((and (equal n '(4)) (not interprogram-paste))
        (car kill-ring))
      (t
        (or kill-ring 
          (let ((debug-on-quit nil))
            (signal 'quit `("The kill-ring is empty."))))
        (let (
            (ARGth-kill-element
              (nthcdr
                (mod (- n (length kill-ring-yank-pointer)) (length kill-ring))
                kill-ring)))
          (unless do-not-move
            (setq kill-ring-yank-pointer ARGth-kill-element)
            (when
                (and
                  yank-pop-change-selection
                  (> n 0)
                  interprogram-cut-function)
              (funcall interprogram-cut-function (car ARGth-kill-element))))
        (car ARGth-kill-element))))))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
(global-set-key (kbd "C-x M-y")
              (lambda ()
                (interactive)
                (insert-string (ns-get-pasteboard))))

(global-set-key (kbd "C-x M-w")
              (lambda ()
                (interactive)
                (when (region-active-p)
                  (ns-set-pasteboard
                   (buffer-substring (region-beginning)
                                     (region-end))))))
```

Answer (score 0):

**simpleclip** might be helpful -

> Simplified access to the system clipboard in Emacs.
>
> simpleclip-mode radically simplifies clipboard handling: the system
>   clipboard and the Emacs kill ring are made completely independent, and
>   never influence each other.
>
> The super keybindings are friendly for OS X: super is generally mapped
>   to the "command" key ie ⌘.
>
> Tested on OS X, X11, and MS Windows

https://github.com/rolandwalker/simpleclip

Answer (score -1):

Use

```lisp
(setq select-enable-clipboard nil)
```

This will only separate the two clipboards, and for <kbd>⌘ c</kbd> and <kbd>⌘ v</kbd> to work like mentioned you will have to rebind them to `clipboard-kill-ring-save` and `clipboard-yank`:

```lisp
(keymap-global-set "s-c" 'clipboard-kill-ring-save)
(keymap-global-set "s-x" 'clipboard-kill-region)
(keymap-global-set "s-v" 'clipboard-yank)
```

I am using this Emacs: https://github.com/railwaycat/emacs-mac-port, and it also works on Emacs 28 built from source.

Comment: I tried this, and no, it does not work. For a solution to work correctly, it should be able to pass the test in steps #1 to #4 above.

Comment: Still does not work. When I do (1) copy text from Chrome to the OSX clipboard, then (2) in Emacs do `kill-line`, then (3) do `clipboard-yank`, it still pastes the killed line from Emacs instead of the desired OSX clipboard text.

Comment: This is the correct answer. No messing around needed with pbpaste or external packages. I've just tried it on OS X, on Emacs built from source.